# Armadillo C++ : Linear Combination with modulus calculations

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, armadillo

I want to extract linear combinations from matrices but by performing combinations in modulus.

Let us consider the calculation modulus 5, we then have the following for the addition:

```
 + |  0 1 2 3 4
 --+-----------
 0 | 0 1 2 3 4
 1 | 1 2 3 4 0
 2 | 2 3 4 0 1
 3 | 3 4 0 1 2 
 4 | 4 0 1 2 3
```

and this table for the multiplication:

```
 * | 0 1 2 3 4
 --+-----------
 0 | 0 0 0 0 0
 1 | 0 1 2 3 4
 2 | 0 2 4 1 3
 3 | 0 3 1 4 2
 4 | 0 4 3 2 1
```

So let us take an example:
Let us consider the following matrix:

```
E = 2 1 3 2 0
    4 3 0 1 1
```

Then we can obtain the triangulation matrix by applying a LU decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) (or a Gaussian Elimination), which is the following:

```
T = 1 0 0 0 0 
    2 1 0 0 0
```

and finally, the matrix that I want to extract, which is the one storing the linear combinations:

```
CL = 3 2 3 0 3
     0 1 1 3 4
     0 0 1 0 0 
     0 0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 0 1
```

So basically, the algorithm should work as follows:

```
 Input: a matrix E with n rows and m columns, and p, a prime number.

 * We perform a Gaussian elimination/LU decomposition to obtain the lower-triangulation matrix T. 
   But all the calculus are done modulo 'p'. 

 Output: T (with the same size as E, n rows m columns). 
         CL (with a size m rows, m columns), 
         which is basically the identity matrix on which we 
         applied all the modifications that were performed on E to obtain T.
```

---

Alright, so now we have the context, let me explain the problem. 
I started to do it using the Armadillo library (http://arma.sourceforge.net/), but I did not find any solution on the library to perform the calculus on a mathematical Field p. I easily found the `LU` method to obtain the lower-triangle matrix, but the calculations are performed in the real.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

    mat A = mat({{2,1,3,2,0},{4,3,0,1,1}});

    mat L, U, P;

    lu(L, U, P, A);

    cout << L << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With the following, you obtain the lower-triangle matrix 'L' but in the real calculus. Thus you obtain:

```
 T' =  1   0
       1/2 1
```

**Is there any technique to perform the computation in a modulus way?**

**EDIT** The Armadillo library is not able to do it. I developed my own LU decomposition in modulus but there is still a bug there. I asked a new question here [Linear Combination C++ in modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648687/linear-combination-c-in-modulus), hoping to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: drop the `using namespace`s, code can become completely unreadable if you do that.

I haven't used Armadillo yet. But I have looked at the documentation, and it seems templated to me.

Now things are getting a bit wild. The type you use, `arma::mat` seems to be a typedef on `arma::Mat<double>`.

The high-level function `arma::lu` isn't properly documented. It obviously does an LU-decomposition, but I don't know if the function is templated. If it is, i.e., you cannot just call it with `double` mats but also other types, you might have a shot using a custom type representing the field (since 5 is prime, otherwise you'd be completely lost) of calculations modulo 5. Meaning you write a class, let's call it `IntMod5` and define all required operators for this class, meaning all operators that IntMod5 uses. For example, you'd need to define `operator/()`, e.g. by making a table of inverses of 4 of the 5 elements of the field (0 has none), i.e. 1->1, 2->3, 3->2, 4->4, and define

```
IntMod5 operator/(const IntMod5& o) const
{
    return IntMod5((this->value*inverse(o.value))%5);
}
```

This is just one example, you likely need to define all arithmetic operators, binary and unary, and possibly more such as comparison (LU decomposition might use finding good pivot elements). If you're lucky and the library is written in a way that it works for any field, not just floating point, you have a chance.

Before you go through all the work, you should use a trivial class simply wrapping double and check if `arma::Mat` or `arma::lu` do any type checks blocking you out.

If either of these fails, you'll likely have to write your own LU decomposition modulo 5 or find another library that supports it.

Comment: the armadillo library uses LAPACK to do its heavy lifting ("Various matrix decompositions are provided through integration with LAPACK") and that will not work with a c++ custom type, so this approach will not with this library

Comment: I did what you proposed, but now I have another problem in my own LU decomposition modulo 5. I asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648687/linear-combination-c-in-modulus