# Linear Combination C++ in modulus

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

I want to compute an LU decomposition of a matrix and extract the linear combinations out of it.

I first asked a question using the library Armadillo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627048/armadillo-c-linear-combination-with-modulus-calculations) but as pointed out by one comment, Armadillo is not able to deal with modulus computation.

Thus I started to develop an LU using prime modulus from scratch, here is what I obtain but there is still a bug that I am not able to see.

Here is the code that I have for now. (Do not think too much about the class Matrix, it is just a way to encapsulate for now a `vector<vector<int>>`.

```
Matrix* Matrix::triangulation(Matrix & ident)
{
    unsigned int n = getNbLines();
    unsigned int m = getNbColumns();

    vector<vector<int>> mat = getMat();

    vector<vector<int>> identity = ident.getMat();
    vector<vector<int>> lower;
    vector<vector<int>> upper;

    /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */  

    /**
     * @brief
     * This code initialize a 'lower' matrix of size 'n x n'.
     * The matrix is fill with only '0'.
     */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        vector<int> v(m);
        lower.push_back(v);

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) lower[i][j] = 0;            
    }   

    /**
     * @brief
     * This code initialize an 'upper' matrix of size 'n x m'.
     * The matrix is fill with only '0'.
     */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        vector<int> v(m);
        upper.push_back(v);
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) upper[i][j] = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @brief
     * This code initialize an 'identity' matrix of size 'm x m'.
     * The matrix is fill with only '0'.
     */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        vector<int> v2(m);
        identity.push_back(v2);
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) identity[i][j] = 0;

        identity[i][i] = 1;
    }

    /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

    // Decomposing matrix into Upper and Lower triangular matrix 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        // Upper Triangular 
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < m; k++) { 

            // Summation of L(i, j) * U(j, k) 
            int sum = 0; 
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
                sum = sum + ((lower[i][j] * upper[j][k])); 

            // Evaluating U(i, k)
            upper[i][k]    = (mat[i][k] - sum) % prime;
            identity[i][k] = (mat[i][k] - sum) % prime;
        } 

        // Lower Triangular 
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < n; k++) { 
            if (i == k) {

                lower[i][i] = 1; // Diagonal as 1 
            }
            else { 

                // Summation of L(k, j) * U(j, i) 
                int sum = 0; 
                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
                    sum = sum + ((lower[k][j] * upper[j][i])); 

                // Evaluating L(k, i) 
                lower[k][i] =    (((mat[k][i] - sum)) / upper[i][i]) % prime; 
                identity[k][i] = (((mat[k][i] - sum)) / upper[i][i]) % prime;                   
            } 
        } 
    }  

    ident.setMat(identity);

    return new Matrix(lower,prime);
}
```

I call it with the object : `Matrix mat({ { 2, 1, 3, 2, 0}, { 4, 3, 0, 1, 1 }},5);`
So basically, I want the LU decomposition (especially the lower-triangle matrix) with all my computation done in modulus 5.

It works to extract the lower-matrix, however, the linear combinations (which are just all the operations done on an identity matrix) are not correct.
Here is the trace that I have with an explanation of what I want to obtain:

```
c |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
c | Prime Number: 5

c |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
c | Input Matrix: 

2 1 3 2 0 
4 3 0 1 1 

c |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
c | Lower Matrix: 

1 0 0 0 0 
2 1 0 0 0 

c |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
c | Linear Combination Matrix:

2 0 3 2 0 
0 1 0 3 1 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 

c |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
c | Expected Solution: 

3 2 3 0 3
0 1 1 3 4
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1

c |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
c | Explanations: 

c | 3 * c1 + 0 * c2 + 0 * c3 + 0 * c4 + 0 * c5 = c1 of Lower-Matrix
c | 2 * c1 + 1 * c2 + 0 * c3 + 0 * c4 + 0 * c5 = c2 of Lower-Matrix
c | 3 * c1 + 1 * c2 + 1 * c3 + 0 * c4 + 0 * c5 = c3 of Lower-Matrix
c | 0 * c1 + 3 * c2 + 0 * c3 + 1 * c4 + 0 * c5 = c4 of Lower-Matrix
c | 3 * c1 + 4 * c2 + 0 * c3 + 0 * c4 + 1 * c5 = c5 of Lower-Matrix

c +=======================================================================================================+
```

So as a small sum-up:

- The lower-matrix is OK, the result is the expected one.
- The linear combinations outputted are not the one expected.
- An explanation of what is expected is given in the last subsection.

**Question: Where is the bug in my way to apply the modification on the identity matrix, and why I do not get in output the correct linear combinations?**

**EDIT**

Clear view of what should happened normally. But the algorithm I did (the LU decomposition) is not exactly the one I do by hand, even though it should lead to the same results. That is the real trouble here...

[image]

Comment: Two things: Have you a clear imagination how things would going on paper? Assuming that - did you debug your algorithm step by step? With a good debugger, you can check in every step whether your code computes what you expect according to your paper/pen sketch. The other thing is a bit OT: matrices stored as `vector`s in `vector`s are really ugly. (But, this is probably not your primary issue.)

Comment: [OT]: `for(unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) lower[i][j] = 0;` is not needed, as `vector<int>(m)` already initialize to `0`.

Comment: @Scheff I add a paper display of how I solve the problem by hand. However, the algorithm I want to apply is much more efficient, should lead to the same results, but unfortunately cannot easily be debugged :/

Comment: _However, the algorithm I want to apply is much more efficient, should lead to the same results, but unfortunately cannot easily be debugged_ I see only one possible answer to this statement: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). ;-) This is what I actually meant: First, become clear on paper how it should work. Then confirm in debugger that it really does work that way (or find out where and why not). This is how software development is done (once you sketched an algorithm in head and implemented it properly (may be)).

Comment: lower[k][i] =    (((mat[k][i] - sum)) / upper[i][i]) % prime; might be your problem, I don't think that is the correct way to do division in modulus

Comment: and you might want to be careful about subtraction as well, because (-3)%5 == -3 in c++ which also may not be what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put my comments into an actual answer: while addition and multiplication modulo prime will do what you expect (note below), subtraction has the pitfall where modulo will return negative results for negative input (e.g. (-3)%5 == -3) and for division you cannot just use integer division, you have to actually implement the inverse of multiplication (for hints, see the answer by Demosthenes in the linked previous question).

Note: unless you overflow, if prime*prime > INT_MAX , you are in trouble for multiplication as well

Comment: I think this is the main issue here, yes. One interesting thing I learned a while back: I used to assume that since most python interpreters are written in C, they will do basic calculations the same way as C (and usually C++) does, and used to test some formulas during implementation phase long before my program will compile using python. Then came modulo, and I figured out that this basic operation, which even has the same syntax as in C, behaves differently. In python,  (-3)%5 will be 2, in C it will be -- as pointed out here -- -3. Best is not to assume anything here.

Comment: By the way, I would even consider implementing operator==() here, with 2==(-3) returning true.